# How to remove certain layers from Fastern-RCNN in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

**Target**: I want to use the pretrained Faster-RCNN model to extract features from image.

**What I have tried**: I use below code to build the model:

```py
import torchvision.models as models
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torch

# download the pretrained fasterrcnn model
model = models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
model.cuda()

# remove [2:] layers
modules = list(model.children())[:2]
model_t=torch.nn.Sequential(*modules)

# load image and extract features
img = Image.open('data/person.jpg')
transform = T.Compose([T.ToTensor()])
img_t = transform(img)
batch_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0).cuda()
ft = model_t(batch_t)
```

**Error**: But I got the following error:`TypeError: conv2d(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple`

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Try model.modules() instead of model.children()

Answer (score 3):

`print(model.modules)` to get the layer names. Then delete a layer with:

```
del model.my_layer_name
```

Comment: This creates a problem when `forward()` defines/uses the deleted module.

Comment: I have seen so many crappy ways of doing this. This must be the cleanest. Thanks @NumesSanguis